# Flask-SQLAlchemy and Third Normal Form

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I achieve 3rd normal form, like having a seperate `Address` model in Flask-SQLAlchemy? The joker is, that I would like to be able to use this seperate model from multiple different models.

For instance, let's say I have two different models, a `Person` and a `Company`:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    street_address = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    postal_code = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    # ...and so on

class Company(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    street_address = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    postal_code = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    # ...and so on
```

Now this is just silly. An address does not depend on whether it's a Person or a Company. So I can make a seperate model, like this:

```
class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    street_address = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    postal_code = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

And then change my person model to be like this:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('address.id'), nullable=False)
    # ...and so on
```

And then add a back reference to my `Address` model:

```
class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    street_address = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    postal_code = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    person = db.relationship('Person', backref='address', lazy=True) # << NEW!
```

However, now I have a design which locks the `Address` to the `Person`. I want all models, which may need an address, to be able to use the model. How do I achieve this?

Comment: `PersonWithAddress` is a meaningless class. Just add the `address.id` as a relationship for both `Person` and `Company`. There is no need for another class for `Person`; if they don't have a known address then the column is simply NULL. I don't know what a "locked" relationship is here that you refer to

Comment: @roganjosh I will only have one `Person` model. I was just trying to point out, when I added the address. Apparently that just caused confusion, so I have removed the `WithAddress` part :-).

Comment: With the edit, I definitely don't follow the question, though. What's stopping you having a `ForeignKey` for both `Company` and `Person` for `Address`?

Comment: `address` is just going to be a table... of addresses. It doesn't matter whether they are for companies or people; the foreign key in each model resolves that issue. That's where I get lost in understanding what you're actually asking. My current reading is that you _think_ you've backed yourself into a corner, and I don't see it

Comment: @roganjosh the very last line of code I have. I thought that I need to add that to my `Addresss` model to "complete" the relationship. But that would mean that the `Address` model now knows of the `Person` model...

Comment: Are we talking about [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) et al. here? That's different to an ORM relationship

Comment: @roganjosh yes, I suppose so. I wasn't aware that it was considered to be different than an ORM relationship. How do I achieve this with flask-sqlalchemy?

Comment: Exactly as you have been doing with your second example of `Person`. Add the ForeignKey and create a relationship on both `Person` and `Company` to `Address`. This does not change the structure of the DB, it's to help the ORM. I'm not sure how this question could be best-answered tbh

Comment: But what about the back reference to person in the `Address` model, can that just be left out?

Comment: There is no need for `backref`. That's also part of the ORM to give an attribute on the parent (either person or company here). You probably want it, though, if you intend to use the ORM. Maybe it would be better to re-formulate the question around the actual issue you're seeing, in light of the fact that `relationship` is not a structural change to the DB

Comment: Ah! Ok, the edit makes your confusion clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not add the `relationship` on `Address`. That table/model is agnostic of whether the address is for a `Person` or a `Company`.

Add the relationship to the parents:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    address_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('address.id'), nullable=False)
    address = db.relationship(Address)
    # ...and so on
```

The `relationship` has nothing to do with any Normal Form, it's to assist the ORM in creating Python objects from query results, and doesn't alter the structure of the database. Adding it to the address relies on `backref` to make the attribute available, which is unnecessarily obscure

Comment: Thank you. I love the times where you end up trying a million different lines of code, and the solution turns out being to remove some code :-)

Comment: Perhaps the downvoter would like to tell me how this doesn't solve the problem?